# exponential growth over time - how do I calculate the increase over a delta-time?

Tags: time, exponential, delta

This is probably a silly / stupid question, but I'm still gonna ask it :
if I have an initial start value at Time 0 (which is in my case always 1.0) and a rate of growth, how do I figure out the increase between Time1 and Time2 ?

Comment: calculate the value at time1 and time2...

Comment: Is your rate an absolute or a relative rate of growth?

Answer (score 0):

Tn = T1 + 0.5 (rate of growth)^2

Dose this make sense? The last term one half of the square of the rate of growth.

Thus the difference between the time periods is

diff(Tn - T1) = 0.5 (rate of growth)^2

Answer (score 0):

increase = value at time2 - value at time1. Seems simple, is simple. The value is equal to T0*(rate of growth)^Ti, where Ti is your time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly:

```
f(t2) - f(t1) where f(t) = initial * growth_factor^t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume a relative rate of growth `r` your value as a function of time is given by

```
f(t) = exp(r*t)
```

(already incorporated `f(0)=1` and `f'(0)=r`) and thus the absolute difference is

```
D = f(t2) - f(t1) = exp(r*t2) - exp(r*t1)
```

while the relative increase is given by

```
d = f(t2)/f(t1) - 1 = exp(r*t2)/exp(r*t1) - 1 = exp(r*(t2-t1)) - 1
```